# How to workaround missing EXT_shader_texture_lod?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, texture-mapping, mipmaps, glsles

I've researched the topic a bit, it seems that the answer is 'impossible' on GLES 2.0 + GLSL, but nevertheless I'd dare to ask again.

In my code, LOD depends not only on distance from camera (in addition, this dependency is unusual), but from camera pitch angle. So far, it seems impossible to simulate that behavior using regular LOD calculation method. But I hope I really missed something. Code is available here
https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd-core/blob/master/src/Map/OpenGL_Common/AtlasMapRenderer_OpenGL_Common.cpp#L226

Comment: There is no need for this extension in OpenGL ES 2.0, you already have `texture2DLod (...)` which allows for lookups at any arbitrary LOD.

Comment: texture2DLod() is available only in vertex shaders, not in fragment ones

Comment: Do you need a discrete LOD? If all you want to do is supplement the traditional mipmap lambda computation based on your camera's pitch angle, you can add a bias to `texture2D (...)`.

Comment: textureLOD would help get rid of noise when doing something like a cubemap convolution. It's an useful feature and bias just doesn't do it.